# Are there any measurement techniques to evaluate the prospective memory (PM) in laboratory?

Tags: memory

The prospective memory (PM) term has been drawing attention since its proposed. But as far as I know, most of the research has been conducted in a real-life situation and there is no measurement technique to evaluate PM in the laboratory. I want to design a research about PM in the laboratory but couldn't cope with that. Are there any laboratory methods to evaluate PM that I haven't known?